# I can't install the bleak module on windows 10

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I get the following error while trying to install bleak using: pip instal bleak (I use spyder via anaconda and I have already tried to solve the problem by downloading visual studio 2022 but that didn't work):

```
Collecting bleak
  Using cached bleak-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Collecting bleak-winrt>=1.0.1
  Using cached bleak-winrt-1.0.1.tar.gz (3.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: bleak-winrt
  Building wheel for bleak-winrt (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Programs\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\JAMESJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyijb89o_'
       cwd: C:\Users\JAMESJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mwbxn_px\bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21
  Complete output (223 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 16 2019

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Running

     'nmake' '-?'

    failed with:

     Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Running

     'nmake' '-?'

    failed with:

     Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/James Jr/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mwbxn_px/bleak-winrt_eef04caefe37478586353ea705688c21/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.6 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  Or with "Visual Studio 2019":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bleak-winrt
Failed to build bleak-winrt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bleak-winrt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I use this to be able to read the live data from the Polar H10 HR Sensor for analytical apllications. So what else can I do?

Comment: Run this from a "Visual Studio 2019 Native tools command prompt" so that your compiler's environment variables are setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had VS2022, but uninstalled it and installed VS 2019 and it worked.  The message states it is looking specifically for VS 2019.
Other issues I encountered was the virus protection was blocking the ninja.exe, so I had the folder whitelisted for the virus protection.